# Amplifier output doubt

Tags: sound, amplifier

So I've been into sound for a while, but there's just one thing that goes over my head. I'll use an example.
Say you have an amplifier, in which datasheet it is specified that it outputs  **300
watts per channel at 8 ohms** . Now my question is: Does this mean that the amp will put out
300 watts when there is a  **total 8 ohm load present** or when  **there is an 8 ohm load present at each channel**  effectively making it a 4 ohm load?

I do have an understanding of voltage, current and Ohm's law, however I am sorry if
I don't understand the answers posted.

Sorry if this has been asked before or is not on topic.

Regards.

Comment: I think it could likely get confused between the engineers & the marketing department, but essentially "*300W per channel at 8Ω*" is 300W into each 8Ω speaker. A stereo amp is effectively 2 amps in this respect, one for each channel [though tied as a pair]

Comment: Ah, so basically, 300 watt per channel into 4 ohm total load, assuming 1 8ohm speaker per channel. Thank you man. Still, I'd like someone else to answer, so I can be safe

Comment: it's not really into a 4Ω load, it's into 2 8Ω loads. They're not in parallel, they're independent loads.

Comment: Oh, okay, thank you man, just like I said to the other guy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so you have an answer and not only comments: Each channel is an independent amp and so a spec that says "300W at 8 ohms" applies separately to each 'half' of the stereo. There is no 4 ohm load (the 8 ohms aren't in parallel) there are two loads of 8 ohms each, one for each channel.

Comment: Oh... So it turns out I had forgotten how an amp works. Thank you both for clearing it up to me, and sorry for asking such a stupid question.

Comment: There are no stupid questions [well, within limits] only stupid answers - of which this isn't one ;)